# Read Variable Length String From HDF5 Dataset Using C API

Tags: c++, c, hdf5, abi, hdf

I'm attempting to read a variable length string from an HDF5 dataset using the C API.  The original C++ code that worked uses `v1.8.15.1` of the HDF5 library.  I decided to drop to C for debugging, as I have more control.

Unfortunately, I'm in a very tough predicament where I'm locked into using **GCC 4.8.5** for my library (due to dependencies), but I'm trying to include this native component in a **Python 3.7** Anaconda package.  In this environment, I'm being forced to use a version of **HDF5** (`v1.10.6-hb1b8bf9_0`) that was compiled using a modern version of **GCC**, so I'm hitting the **GCC 5** ABI break boundary.
I'm dealing with conflicting requirements and I'd rather find a solution to this problem, as this is the only issue between me and success.  The uglier / more difficult solution involves custom library builds and lugging around custom-built conda packages - which, I would like to avoid.

Note: I'm only calling functions on the **HDF5** library that use primitive C types (i.e., no **STL** types), so theoretically, I'm thinking this should be possible - all the other APIs seem to work fine.  Maybe my assumptions is flawed.  Anyway, I'll pose the question to see if anyone can offer some insight before I dig deeper into the **HDF5** library.

When viewing the dataset in **HDFView**, it has the following properties:

```
DATATYPE  H5T_STRING{
    STRSIZE H5T_VARIABLE;
    STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
    CSET H5T_CSET_UTF8;
    CTYPE H5T_C_S1;}
```

The code I sandboxed to read the dataset is:

```
#include "hdf5.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    hid_t hfile, dset, space_id;
    int storage_size;
    herr_t status;
    char* s;
    int i;

    // open file and dataset
    hfile = H5Fopen("input.hdf5", H5F_ACC_RDONLY, H5P_DEFAULT);
    dset = H5Dopen(hfile, "/path/to/my_dataset", H5P_DEFAULT);

    // create memtype
    // Note: I removed the status checks for readability, they are all zero
    memtype = H5Tcopy(H5T_C_S1);
    status = H5Tset_size(memtype, H5T_VARIABLE);
    status = H5Tset_strpad(memtype, H5T_STR_NULLTERM);
    status = H5Tset_cset(memtype, H5T_CSET_UTF8);

    // get the storage size and space_id
    storage_size = H5Dget_storage_size(dset);
    space_id = H5Dget_space(dset);

    // allocate string buffer
    char* s = (char*)malloc(storage_size * sizeof(char));
    memset(s, 0, storage_size);

    // read string from dataset
    status = H5Dread(dset, memtype, space_id, H5S_ALL, H5P_DEFAULT, s);

    // printing the string buffer is problematic because it was not populated / null-terminated properly
    //printf("val: %s", s);

    // convert to integers to see what was returned
    for (i = 0; i < storage_size; i++)
        printf("s[%d]: %d\n", i, s[i]);

    free(s); s = 0;
    status = H5Sclose(space_id);
    status = H5Tclose(memtype);
    status = H5Dclose(dset);
    status = H5Fclose(hfile);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
s[0]: -128
s[1]: 38
s[2]: -24
s[3]: 0
s[4]: 0
s[5]: 0
s[6]: 0
s[7]: 0
s[8]: 0
s[9]: 0
s[10]: 0
s[11]: 0
s[12]: 0
s[13]: 0
s[14]: 0
s[15]: 0
```

To run the code, please create and activate a conda virtual environment with the HDF5 library installed using these commands:

```bash
conda create python=3.7 hdf5 -n hdf5TestVenv
conda activate hdf5TestVenv
```

As you can see, I'm getting junk filled in the provided `char` buffer.  I've tried many variations on the memory type, size, strpad, and cset - none of them worked (most resulted in nothing being populated).  Based on the properties from **HDFView**, I think I'm setting up the call correctly, but again, maybe my assumption that I can call this library from a **GCC 4.8.5** library is flawed.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Here is my *Makefile*:

```
PROGRAM = hdfTest

INCS = -I. -I$(CONDA_PREFIX)/include
LIBDIRS = -L $(CONDA_PREFIX)/lib
EXTRALIB = -lpthread -lrt -lz -ldl -lm

LIBS = -lhdf5 $(EXTRALIB)
LDFLAGS = $(LIBDIRS) $(LIBS)

CSOURCES = main.c
COBJECTS = $(CSOURCES:.c=.o)
CFLAGS = -DESRI_UNIX $(INCS)
CC = gcc -fPIC -fsigned-char -m64 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter

all: clean $(PROGRAM)

.PHONY: all debug clean

debug: CC += -DDEBUG -g
debug: clean $(PROGRAM)

$(PROGRAM): $(COBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(COBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    $(RM) -f $(COBJECTS) $(PROGRAM)
```

Update 8/14/20 @ 14:24:

I tried to read the data as a blob directly out of the dataset with the thought that I could convert it externally in my library / external to HDF5, but I keep getting "datatype conversion" errors.  If anyone knows how to brute-force the read to a raw memory buffer, this would be enough to get me over the hurdle so I can move on.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: mm.. isn't it meant to be a utf8 string?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I took the tour and read the "How to Ask" article already.  I thought I was following all the guidelines.  I also thought I provided a minimal reproducible example, but maybe it was not complete enough, so I updated it to be fully complete.  Please let me know if I'm sill missing anything.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie it is a UTF8 string, I set the cset accordingly:

`status = H5Tset_cset(memtype, H5T_CSET_UTF8);`

Comment: @arj but you're trying to use ansi version of C functions (ones that work only with 7/8 bit character).

Comment: Isn't UTF8 8-bit?  I tried using the C++ interface (e.g., `H5::DataSet`) and experienced the same problem.  Are there other functions you think I should try?

Comment: regarding the makefile: 1) `INCS = -I. -I$(CONDA_PREFIX)/include`  The macro: `CONDO_PREFIX` not defined.  2) the file to be compiled is named: `main.cpp` so will be compiled as a C++ file, not C.  3) the `all` target should be proceeded by: `.PHONY: all debug clean`  4) to avoid repeated evaluations of the macros.  should use: `:=` not `=`

Comment: regarding: `int main(int argc, char const *argv[])`  This will cause the compiler to output two warning messages about unused parameters.  Suggest using the other valid signature for `main()`  `int main( void )`

Comment: OT: regarding: `char* s = (char*)malloc(storage_size * sizeof(char));`  1) In C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code (and is error prone).  Suggest removing that cast.  2) the expression: `sizeof( char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect and just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that expression.  3) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding the statement pair: `char* s = (char*)malloc(storage_size * sizeof(char));
    memset(s, 0, storage_size);`   Strongly suggest calling: `calloc()` (note its' parameter list) to replace both those statements.

Comment: why bother to `malloc()` and `free()` when you can use the `Variable Length Array` feature of C and simply say:  `char s[ storage_size ];`

Comment: @user3629249 sorry for the confusion, I updated the code to be pure C and updated the Makefile with your suggestions.  As you could probably tell, this originated as a C++ application.  ```CONDA_PREFIX``` is an environment variable set when activating a conda virtual environment - I added those instructions as well.  Your other suggestions will not have an impact on the behavior of the application.  Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
for (int i = 0; i < storage_size; i++)
    printf("s[%d]: %d\n", i, s[i]);
```

an integer `int` is either 4 or 8 bytes long (depending on the underlying hardware and certain options to the compile statement.)

So each byte is not a separate integer.

also, this will cause the compiler to output a warning about conversion of a `char` to 'ptr to int' without a cast.

suggest:

```
for (int i = 0; i < storage_size; i += sizeof( int ) )
    printf("s[%d]: %d\n", i, &s[i]);
```

However, that will increment `i` by the `sizeof( int )` for each iteration, which you probably do not want.  Therefore, suggest a second index:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < storage_size; i += sizeof( int ), j++ )
    printf("s[%d]: %d\n", j, &s[i]);
```

Note: some integer references are stored Big Endian and some are stored Little Endian, you need to keep that in your considerations.

Suggest [HDF5 user guide](https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/HDF5/HDF5+User+Guides?preview=/53610087/53610088/Users_Guide.pdf)  then 'drill' down to the actual user guide, then read: code section: `Code Example 6-30. Set the string datatype size to H5T_VARIABLE`  and  `Code Example 6-31. Read variable-length strings into Cstrings`

Comment: ```i``` is an integer that's being used to index into the ```s``` char array
sorry, none of what you are suggesting is necessary

Comment: does this mean that you want to display the numeric value of each byte of the array?

Comment: Please see my code comment, I cast the `char` to an `int` so I can see what the HDF5 library populated.  I have already read examples `6-30` and `6-31`, that's basically what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the string was being stored in a 2D array within the dataset.  The solution ended up being passing the address of the pointer to the `char` array that was allocated. (sigh)

```
// allocate string buffer
char* s = (char*)malloc(storage_size * sizeof(char));
memset(s, 0, storage_size);

// read string from dataset
status = H5Dread(dset, memtype, space_id, H5S_ALL, H5P_DEFAULT, &s);
```

This became apparent after querying the dimensions with the following APIs:
`H5Sget_simple_extent_ndims`, `H5Sget_simple_extent_dims`

Thanks for your help, everyone!